# Error while starting a blank app with Ionic framework

Tags: node.js, git, cordova, ionic-framework

I recently installed ionic framework.

My laptop already had GIT, node and npm installed and all of them have been updated to latest.

When running `ionic start my IonicApp1 tabs` following the Get Started instruction on their website, I ran into the following error and this stopped from creating the app.

Any idea? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I ran this and had no problems. Try re-installing Git and make sure you check the box that allows it to be run from Windows command line. Alternatively, try running from bash.

Comment: Yes, I re-installed the latest Git 2.13 64-bit. And reran the command but still received the same error. Git installation allowed all default settings and checked Windows Command Line and Console in particularly.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic recently changed its cli try `ionic start myproject blank --type ionic1` for a blank demo app